# ruby global variable dollar sign semicolon ($;) regex equivilant

Tags: ruby, split, string

I have a string `"\nbed.bed_id,\nbed.bed_label,\nbed.room_id,\nbed.pool_bed, nbed.record_state\n"`and I need to split it by white space and comma.

I tried `split(/,?\s+/)` which works but also leaves a `""` at the beginning.

Using `split($;)` doesn't. What I'm looking for is say `split(/,?$;/)` is there a way to retain the default functionality and just add to it?

(p.s I know I can do this split[1..-1], there are so many ways to do things in ruby).

**update**:

- My issue was with `$;` I wasn't sure really what it was and thought it had special meaning, because as a variable `irb>$; #=> nil`. Now it may be that I missed it, or that the documentation has been updated but, ruby-doc.org says "If pattern is omitted, the value of $; is used. If $; is nil (which is the default), str is split on whitespace as if ` ‘ were specified."
- As well, `$;` is from Perl or awk, known as the SUBSEP, and a further explanation as to why the beginning is stripped away with `$;` is here [Why is split(' ') trying to be (too) smart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301372/why-is-split-trying-to-be-too-smart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't avoid split() from returning some empty elements at the start or end in this case?

Try rejecting empty strings from the array:

```
string.split(/,?\s+/).reject &:empty?
```

Comment: I like the use of the pretzel operator!

Comment: "You can't avoid split() from returning some empty elements at the start or end in this case?", the default split doesn't return empty elements at the beginning while /\s+/ does
split() =>["bed.bed_id,", "bed.bed_label,", "bed.room_id,", "bed.pool_bed,", "nbed.record_state"]

split(/\s+/) => ["", "bed.bed_id,", "bed.bed_label,", "bed.room_id,", "bed.pool_bed,", "nbed.record_state"]

Answer (score -1):

With using split u can do it

str = "\nbed.bed_id,\nbed.bed_label,\nbed.room_id,\nbed.pool_bed, nbed.record_state\n"

```
st = str.split(/,?\s+/)
st.shift
st
```

Comment: ... and if the string does *not* start with white-spaces you throw away the 1st element.