# Why is split(' ') trying to be (too) smart?

Tags: ruby, string, split, implementation

I just discovered the following odd behavior with `String#split`:

```
"a\tb c\nd".split
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

"a\tb c\nd".split(' ')
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

"a\tb c\nd".split(/ /)
=> ["a\tb", "c\nd"]
```

[The source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_0/string.c#L5869) (string.c from 2.0.0) is over 200 lines long and contains a passage like this:

```
/* L 5909 */
else if (rb_enc_asciicompat(enc2) == 1) {
    if (RSTRING_LEN(spat) == 1 && RSTRING_PTR(spat)[0] == ' '){
        split_type = awk;
    }
}
```

Later, in the code for the `awk` split type, the actual argument isn't even used any more and does the same as a plain `split`.

- Does anyone else feel that this is somehow broken?
- Are there good reasons for this?
- Does “magic” like that happen more often than most people might think in Ruby?

Comment: Why is something that is documented being "too smart"? It's an intended default behavior that you can override if you choose by passing it an alternate pattern to use for splitting text.

Comment: With too smart i mean ruby guesses that i want to split at all whitespace characters, where i am literally telling it to split at spaces.

Comment: I am going to vote to close this question as i am realizing that there probably isn't a general, satisfying answer to this question. Thanks for all your answers and comments!

Comment: Actually there is a reason, as I put in my answer. Whether it's satisfying is up to you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's consistent with Perl's `split()` behavior. Which in turn is based on [Gnu `awk`'s](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) `split()`. So it's a long-standing tradition with origins in Unix.

From the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) on `split`:

> As another special case, split emulates the default behavior of the
>   command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a literal
>   string composed of a single space character (such as ' ' or "\x20" ,
>   but not e.g. / / ). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is
>   removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as
>   if it were /\s+/ ; in particular, this means that any contiguous
>   whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator.
>   However, this special treatment can be avoided by specifying the
>   pattern / / instead of the string " " , thereby allowing only a single
>   space character to be a separator.

Comment: I played around a bit with Perl's split and noticed that this actually makes sense in Perl, because it needs an argument. An empty string wouldn't work because that is another special case (returns an array of characters, as in ruby). The closest thing to calling split without an argument in Perl was `split(undef, $str)` but this actually behaves like `split('', $str)`, not like `split(' ', $str)` so i guess it is not quite consistent :). After all, arguing about why things are like this and that in Perl was already done all too often so i'll stop here :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split), this part in particular:

> If pattern is a String, then its contents are used as the delimiter
>   when splitting str. If pattern is a single space, str is split on
>   whitespace, with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace
>   characters ignored.
>
> If pattern is omitted, the value of $; is used. If $; is nil (which is
>   the default), str is split on whitespace as if ` ‘ were specified.

You can use a regexp to split the string.

Comment: Thanks! I have read the documentation. My question is more like “Should we go and fix this, or is there good reason for this?”

Comment: At least we know that it is intended. We can try to find the reason why Matz designed so, and we can also claim that this is strange. But you cannot "go and fix it". Whomever decides is Matz.

Comment: Of course Matz decides about the future of MRI. But we can still walk up to him an point at possible improvements ;)

Comment: Maybe he designed it this way because the default case will most likely be as it is implemented right now, namely splitting on whitespace in general. Since the Ruby language focuses heavily on making as much as possible easier on the programmer, this might have been part of the thought process behind it (this is guesswork on my part). We can still use Regexp for the cases where the default behaviour isn't desirable.

Comment: I am not saying the default behavior is wrong (when called without arguments), it is actually incredibly useful. But why should a method do the same thing when you pass it a special argument, especially when it behaves differently for all other characters?

Comment: It's consistent with Perl's `split()` behavior. Which in turn is based on Gnu `awk`. So it's a long-standing tradition with origins in Unix.